# C# 4.0 Feedback

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, feedback

Does anyone know the official method for submitting feedback on C# 4.0 so that Anders and his team will get the feedback and be able to respond to the submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vs2010ctpvbcs/threads/), or (for bugs) [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback) (they've added options for .NET 4.0 CTP and VS2010 CTP)

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across the VS10 CTP feedback forum on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/vs2010ctp/

and the specific C# and VB forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vs2010ctpvbcs/threads/